# Can I sell critters such as a rabbit?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have three NPCs so far, and none of them will accept critters, like rabbits, squirrels, etc. I read the Terraria Wiki and it claims that you can sell critters, but I can't find that. Maybe it's only on computer, and I just misread it.

Answer (score 1):

On the mobile version of terraria you can't sell critters (I don't know why) even though you can on the pc edition. When mobile goes to 1.3 you will probably be able to sell critters, because you can sell critters on pc 1.3. Also the problem might be that you hit a key on the keyboard to sell and item on pc (I think), and you can't hit a key on mobile.